# How to make a Back <button>

Tags: javascript, html

How do i run an external `javascript` file when a `<button>` is pressed in `html`?

I'm trying to make a **Back** `<button>` to be placed across all pages. The functionality is such that once the `<button>` is clicked, **don't go to a previous page if the previous page isn't the same site.**

For example, if you were previously on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) before you loaded the site, and you click this back button, it should not take you back to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Otherwise, if you were on the same website prior to the current page then it should send you to the previous page.

Here's what i currently have:

**markup file**

```html
<a href="back button.js" class="nav2">&#8592;</a>
```

**script file**

```js
if (document.title="Personal database") {
    history.go(0)"onmouseover="self-status.referrer;return
}
```

[This script was taken mostly from this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRcN1i7xcZE) on creating a Back `<button>`, but the creater showed it going from the site back to twitter login
which is something i don't want hence why i've put it into an `if` statement.

Comment: wont let my edit it so ill just add this here "back button.js"
`if (document.title="Personal database") {
 history.go(0)"onmouseover="self-status.referrer;return
} else {
 history.go(-1)"onmouseover="self-status.referrer;return
}`

Comment: Just use `document.referrer` to get the previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video is a little different from what you've tried to do . It's using embedded JS in the html, so, note that importantly onMouseOver is a property of the `<a>`, and not javascript.

This means that your code won't work when you pull it into a separate JS file like this, and that your JS should look like:

In **backbtn.js**:

```
function backbtn() {
    if(document.title="Personal Database") {
      history.go(0);
    }
    else {
      history.go(-1);
   }
```

}

In **index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Personal Database</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="backbtn.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  an example backlink using video method:
  <a href="javascript:if(document.title = 'Personal Database'){history.go(0)} else{history.go(-1)}" onmouseover="self-status.referrer;return true">This is a backClick</a></br>
  an example backlink method referencing function from js file
  <a href="javascript:backbtn()" onMouseOver="self-status.referrer;return true">This is a backClick 2</a>
</body>

</html>
```